# Hibernate refresh() causes stack overflow due recursion on embedded component

Tags: hibernate, components, refresh, stack-overflow

I have a legacy database which I'm trying to access using Hibernate 3.

In this database I have two entities: **A** and **B**, and third entity **C** which represent a relation between **A** and **B**. The **C** entity holds also some additional information about the relation, so it cannot be coded just as @ManyToMany.

The **C** entity refers the **A** and **B** entities using @Id and @ManyToOne annotations.
The **A** and **B** entities list the **C** entity as sets using @OneToMany annotation.

The underlying database may change, so I try to use the Hibernate **refresh()** procedure to re-read data for the **A** entity from the database.

This causes and endless recursion loop: **A**->**C**->**A**->**C**... which results in stack overflow.

It seems this **refresh()** procedure tries to refresh every reference, including the lazy ones, with unlimited depth. This is not that is really necessary for me, it would suffice, if I could make a "shallow" refresh and reset all @OneToMany sets back to the "uninitialized" state.

So my question is:

How can I **avoid this endless recursion**,

or

how can I just **"reset" an entity back to "uninitialized" state**.

Below is a part of stack trace produced with Eclipse.

```
SingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).load(Serializable, Object, LockOptions, SessionImplementor) line: 3293
DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 496
DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 477
DefaultLoadEventListener.load(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 227
DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 285
DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 152
SessionImpl.fireLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 1090
SessionImpl.internalLoad(String, Serializable, boolean, boolean) line: 1038
ManyToOneType(EntityType).resolveIdentifier(Serializable, SessionImplementor) line: 630
ManyToOneType(EntityType).resolve(Object, SessionImplementor, Object) line: 438
EmbeddedComponentType(ComponentType).resolve(Object, SessionImplementor, Object) line: 617
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).extractKeysFromResultSet(Loadable[], QueryParameters, ResultSet, SessionImplementor, EntityKey[], LockMode[], List) line: 722
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).getRowFromResultSet(ResultSet, SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, LockMode[], EntityKey, List, EntityKey[], boolean) line: 606
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).doQuery(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 829
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 274
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).loadEntity(SessionImplementor, Object, Type, Object, String, Serializable, EntityPersister, LockOptions) line: 2037
CascadeEntityLoader(AbstractEntityLoader).load(SessionImplementor, Object, Object, Serializable, LockOptions) line: 86
CascadeEntityLoader(AbstractEntityLoader).load(Serializable, Object, SessionImplementor, LockOptions) line: 76
SingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).load(Serializable, Object, LockOptions, SessionImplementor) line: 3293
DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 496
DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 477
DefaultLoadEventListener.load(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 227
DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(LoadEvent, EntityPersister, EntityKey, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 285
DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 152
SessionImpl.fireLoad(LoadEvent, LoadEventListener$LoadType) line: 1090
SessionImpl.internalLoad(String, Serializable, boolean, boolean) line: 1038
ManyToOneType(EntityType).resolveIdentifier(Serializable, SessionImplementor) line: 630
ManyToOneType(EntityType).resolve(Object, SessionImplementor, Object) line: 438
EmbeddedComponentType(ComponentType).resolve(Object, SessionImplementor, Object) line: 617
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).extractKeysFromResultSet(Loadable[], QueryParameters, ResultSet, SessionImplementor, EntityKey[], LockMode[], List) line: 722
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).getRowFromResultSet(ResultSet, SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, LockMode[], EntityKey, List, EntityKey[], boolean) line: 606
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).doQuery(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 829
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(SessionImplementor, QueryParameters, boolean) line: 274
CascadeEntityLoader(Loader).loadEntity(SessionImplementor, Object, Type, Object, String, Serializable, EntityPersister, LockOptions) line: 2037
CascadeEntityLoader(AbstractEntityLoader).load(SessionImplementor, Object, Object, Serializable, LockOptions) line: 86
CascadeEntityLoader(AbstractEntityLoader).load(Serializable, Object, SessionImplementor, LockOptions) line: 76
SingleTableEntityPersister(AbstractEntityPersister).load(Serializable, Object, LockOptions, SessionImplementor) line: 3293
DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(RefreshEvent, Map) line: 151
DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(RefreshEvent) line: 62
SessionImpl.fireRefresh(RefreshEvent) line: 1118
SessionImpl.refresh(Object) line: 1098
EntityManagerImpl(AbstractEntityManagerImpl).refresh(Object, LockModeType, Map<String,Object>) line: 903
EntityManagerImpl(AbstractEntityManagerImpl).refresh(Object) line: 878
```

...

Comment: Check that the `equals` and `hashcode` methods are implemented properly as Hibernate should detect that there's a loop and stop loading entities. But, if hashcode or equals are buggy, it won't detect the duplicates.

Comment: Has checked this. Does not help. Hibernate doesn't call any of these methods in this endless loop.

Answer (score 4):

I removed the CascadeType.REFRESH attribute from @OneToMany declaration. Now Hibernate re-reads the @OneToMany collection, but does not try to re-read its members.

Looks like a workaround, but it is what I need.

Comment: I just got bit with this using Hibernate 4.3.5.Final, and changing `CascadeType.ALL` into `{PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE}` fixed the problem. Thanks a bunch!